# How to locate the app which defines global keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, shortcuts-app

I used a macOS app to define a few keyboard shortcuts to open/activate other apps quickly since a few years ago, now I want to update the settings in that app, but I can't remember which app it is.

Any there any workarounds to help me locate it? I through that app had registered some settings to system settings, so I could find it in system preferences level?

BTW, the app may request the `Accessibility` in `Privacy`, but I didn't find any doubtable items.

Comment: So you should still have it in Applications. I don’t know how you expect us to know the one you used… Which ones have you found so far, so we don’t repeat.

Comment: @SolarMike I do confirmed it's not Thor, Manico, AltTab, but it must be someone like that. I also checked out the user processes, no related ones. So I'm looking for a reversed solution to locate the app, like inspecting a UIElement by Inspector.

Comment: More context: I defined `F1` key to open iTerm, `F2` to open Google Chrome...

Comment: Might it be `System Preferences… > Keyboard > Text Replacement`?